# 画面遷移の際にデータベースのidを渡す方法がわかりません

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-intent

## やりたいこと

Kotlinで「ListViewの各項目をタップすると、その項目に対応した内容の詳細画面が表示される」という流れを作りたいです。

1. タップした項目が持つid(PrimaryKey)を詳細画面の方に渡す
2. 詳細画面は受け取ったidからデータベースを検索し対応するレコードの値をすべて表示する

## 問題点

タップした項目が持つidを取得し詳細画面に渡す方法がわかりません

## 現状

putExtraで適当なテキストを送り、詳細画面でトースト表示させています

## コード(一部抜粋)

MainActivity.kt

```
// 各項目をタップ → 詳細画面に遷移
MainListView.setOnItemClickListener{_, _, _, _ ->
    val intent: Intent = Intent(this, DetailActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("TapID", "タップした項目のID")
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

DetailActivity.kt

```
class DetailActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail)

        Toast.makeText(this, "${intent.extras.get("TapID")}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Comment: 現在実装しているコードを記述できますか？また、遷移する前に値は取得できていますか？質問に追記してください。

Comment: わからないのは、タップした項目が持つidを取得する方法ですか? それとも詳細画面に渡す方法ですか? もし両方であれば、別々の質問にするのが良いと思います。

Comment: コードを追記しました。確認よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: わかりにくく書いてしまい申し訳ありませんでした。わからないのはidを取得する方法です。

Answer (score 1):

ListView を使っているということは、その ListView に Adapter を渡していると思います。

Adapter として ArrayAdapter を使っているのであれば、ArrayAdapter に何らかの配列を渡していると思います。その配列の要素の中にレコードの id が必要です。

以下のようにすると、ArrayAdapter に渡してある配列の中の該当要素を取得することができ、
その要素から id を取得することができます。

```
MainListView.setOnItemClickListener { parent, _, position, _ ->
    // 該当の要素を取得
    val listView = parent as ListView
    val item = listView.getItemAtPosition(position) as Item     // 該当要素を取得

    // id を渡す
    val intent: Intent = Intent(this, DetailActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("TapID", item.id)                           // 該当要素から id を取得して intent にセット
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

(`Item` は配列の要素の型に読み替えてください)

---

コメントを受けて追記します。

ArrayAdapter に String[] を渡しているということでしょうか?
であれば、String に id を持たせることはできませんので、以下のように修正が必要になります。

まず、Item クラスを定義します。

```
private inner class Item(val id: Long, val name: String) {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return name
    }
}
```

これで、ListView に表示する文字列とデータベースの id をペアにして扱うことができます。

次に、今、

```
string_array = emptyMutableListOf<String>()
string_array.add(1つめの文字列)
string_array.add(2つめの文字列)
// ...

adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(context, resource, string_array);
```

という感じで ArrayAdapter を作っていると思いますので、

```
item_array = emptyMutableListOf<Item>()
item_array.add(Item(1つ目のid, 1つめの文字列))
item_array.add(Item(2つ目のid, 2つめの文字列))
// ...

adapter = ArrayAdapter<Item>(context, resource, item_array);
```

というように、Item の配列(上記コードではリストになっていますが、どちらでも大丈夫のはずです)を渡すように変更します。

そして、この adapter を使った ListView なら、

```
MainListView.setOnItemClickListener { parent, _, position, _ ->
    // 該当の要素を取得
    val listView = parent as ListView
    val item = listView.getItemAtPosition(position) as Item         // 該当要素を取得

    // id を渡す
    val intent: Intent = Intent(this, DetailActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("TapID", item.id)                               // 該当要素から id を取得して intent にセット
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

というように item から id が取得できます。

他にも手を加える必要のある箇所が出てくるかもしれませんが、適宜修正してください。

(こちらの `Item` は `String` に読み替えないで下さい)

Comment: ”as Item”のところunresolved referenceとエラーが出てしまいます。CripData.Itemじゃないかというような文が出てきたりしたのでいろいろ書き換えてみましたができませんでした…。

Comment: @akari Item は配列の要素の型に読み替えてください。

Comment: as Stringに変更し、putExtraのitemは.idをつけるとエラーが出たのでitemのままにしました。データベースのidは相変わらず取れません…。

Comment: @akari 回答に追記しました。

Comment: 解決しました！！idをLong型には変換できないと怒られたのでString型に直して動かしてます。丁寧に教えていただきありがとうございました(´∀｀)

Comment: id は String 型だったのですね。整数だと思い込んでいました。失礼しました。

Answer (score 0):

`intent`に向けて`ExtraData`を`put`しているので、
遷移先で取得する際は`Intent`を取得して、`intent`から`ExtraData`を`get`してください。

DetailActivity.kt

```
class DetailActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail)

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String tapid = intent.getStringExtra("TapID");
        Toast.makeText(this, tapid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Comment: 書き方参考にさせていただきました！ありがとうございます！